# Selenium: Why does click() not behave like it does in firefox?

Tags: java, junit, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a link with an id:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false();" id="lol">
```

In my test:

```
selenium.click("lol"); //when running the test, the click will just end up selecting the item, not firing off the frameworks javascript
```

This does not register the click the same! There is javascript that is part of a complex framework which will cause a div to popup. This works in firefox.

But this does work as a fix:

```
selenium.click("lol"); //when running the test, the click will just end up selecting the item, not firing off the frameworks javascript
selenium.keyPress("lol", "\\13"); //press enter key, since the click ended up selecting it
```

The fix does work. However, what is going on here? It seems that selenium.click() != [actual browser click event]. Can anyone help shed some light on these inner workings?

Comment: This seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633600/selenium-click-event-seems-not-to-be-always-triggered-results-in-timeout -- it seems that it is unknown why this happens, but you can use fireEvent() to properly simulate events.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium sometimes does not simulate click on javascript hrefs exactly. Maybe its the same issue here. A quick fix is to use a combination of selenium's mousedown and mouseup events. You can also consider using `selenium.fireEvent("lol","click");`. Revert back when you have tried these.

Comment: I did try this. It did not work :( Oh... but perhaps mousedown and mouseup will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to click a link in a browser before the javascript is loaded. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916554/link-clicking-before-javascript-loads-problem). One solution would be to wait for some element to be visible on the page that is put there by javascript.

Comment: I actually do wait for it to be visible on the page.